# XFX Radeon HD5870 causes every game and application that is hardware accelerated to crash at startup

Tags: graphics-card, crash

As my title says, every game and application that is hardware accelerated crashes at startup. I have tried to disable the graphics card and then visual studio 2010 and expression blend works. When I enable it it crashes on startup.

Same thing with games such as PES 2011 and Battlefield play for free.

How can I solve this issue? I have tried procmon from Sysinternals but cannot find any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It wasn't actually the graphics card but MSI Afterburner. After killing the MSI Afterburner process; everyhing works.

Answer (score 0):

If updating drivers doesn't fix it, you've probably got a bad card. Try and exchange it for another if you can.

Comment: Ok, tanks for that answer. Don't have another AIT card but I have a Nvidia card so I'll change to that one. I'm pretty sure I got drivers from Windows Update, and after that update it might have stopped working. Not sure though.